# cf10 issue with cfquery maxrows

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I recently moved an application from cf9 to cf10

When running a query that has maxrows set, I receive the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=1000' at line 1
```

The query runs fine on cf9 and cf8.

Doing a bit of playing around, it looks like cf10 is prepending the query with `OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=1000;` but mySQL doesn't recognise it.  If I take the maxrows setting out of the query it runs fine.

Also worth noting, the query has two outer joins.

Did anyone else experience similar issues when moving to cf10?

Thanks in advance for any advice

Here is the full query

```
<cfquery name="details" datasource="#Application.ds#" maxrows="#arguments.maxrows#">
          SELECT b.booking_id,
                    DATEDIFF(b.check_out,b.check_in) as nights,
                    b.package_id,
                    b.beds_cot,
                    b.date_booked,
                    b.beds_king,
                    b.status,
                    b.tstamp as booking_tstamp,
                    g.ext_ref_id as guest_ext_ref_id,
                    g.title,
                    g.first_name,
                    g.surname,
                    g.full_name,
                    g.tstamp as guest_tstamp,
                    r.room_id,
                    r.ext_ref_id as room_ext_ref_id,
                    r.name as room_name,
                    r.description as room_description,
                    p.package_id,
                    p.ext_ref_id as package_ext_ref_id,
                    p.name as package_name,
                    p.description as package_description,
                    p.date_start as pacakge_date_start,
                    p.date_end as package_date_end

          FROM guest_booking as b 
          JOIN guest as g
          LEFT JOIN room as r ON b.room_id = r.room_id
          LEFT JOIN packages as p on b.package_id = p.package_id

          WHERE b.provider_id = #arguments.provider_id#
            and b.guest_id = g.guest_id
          <cfif isdefined("arguments.status")>
              and b.status = #arguments.status#
          </cfif>
          <cfif isdefined("arguments.booking_id")>
              and b.booking_id = #arguments.booking_id#
          </cfif>

          ORDER BY #arguments.order_by#
        </cfquery>
```

Comment: Not sure why that is happening but you may find the mySQL LIMIT clause as an alternative. More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Sounds like an incompatibility between driver version and MySQL version? I'd probably just go with using LIMIT as Sam suggests, rather than trying to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks Sam. LIMIT as you suggested is working fine.  Works for me moving forward as well.  If I haven't received a direct solution to problem described in a day or so, please post as answer and I can flag as such.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Jason - I think Sam's suggestion is good solution too. FWIW I suspect Peter is right about it being a version incompatibility because it worked fine for me "MySQL(4/5)" and MySQL 5.1.62+.

Comment: I am currently running on mysql(4/5) and mySQL5.6.5.  I assume driver that came with cf10 is latest, and mySQL 5.6.5 is fairly current..  I'm good to move ahead with LIMIT clause, but would be interesting to know if this is an issue with latest drivers/db.  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: If I get a chance I will try it with 5.6 later to see if my results differ.

Comment: @Sam Farmer. Could you post your comment as an answer and I can tick it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: This issue has resurfaced for me.  I tried to install a Mura plugin and got this error.  It is a clean Mura Install, with a downloaded plugin.  All works fine if I install on Windows/cf9, but I get this error on OSX/cf10.  I still can't find anything about this online.. anyone got any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why that is happening but you may find the mySQL `LIMIT` clause as an alternative. More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 3):

Maxrows has always been something I'd avoid.

I'm not sure how ColdFusion handles this, but I remember hearing (at least when CF7 was around) that CF actually gets a larger data-set, then splits it at the CF server level and NOT at the SQL database level. As you can imagine, that may have an unwanted performance hit,

I am not sure what your exact problem is (sounds like a bug to me), but I would strongly recommend swapping out the maxrows attribute for a combination of `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses in your SQL (cfquery).

The benefit, is that this is standard SQL and may actually run faster than CF maxrows anyway, whilst also eliminating your problem.

Comment: Yes, I believe that was true in early versions. However, their error message suggests CF10 is limiting the records [on the database side](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_select_limit), as `LIMIT` does. But unless the behavior is documented, I agree with using `LIMIT` as Sam suggested earlier. Still it is interesting to see that maxrows is a little smarter than I thought ;-)

Comment: Ahh good point! Seems like it would be a nice feature actually. Never really use it myself.

Comment: (Edit) If it was consistent, and documented, yes. Since I am never sure whether `maxrows` executes in the database or in CF, from one version to the next, `LIMIT` is probably the safer bet ;-)